# Is outputting the array in Bicep in this example the correct way?

Tags: azure, azure-bicep, infrastructure-as-code

Hi Looking at the final line. Is this an acceptable way of outputting the array ? Or is there a better way ?

```
@description('This is the location which needs to be provided, this is the Azure region')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var storageAccountSku = 'standard_LRS'

resource storageAccounts 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = [for i in range(0, 4): {
  name: '${i}mystorage1234'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountSku
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}]

output storageNames array = [for i in range(0,4) : storageAccounts[i].name]
```

Thank you in advance,

Jason

PS : I tried to look for the answer on Microsoft pages but didn't see

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's fine, although here's how I'd tweak it.

```
@description('This is the location which needs to be provided, this is the Azure region')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

param numberOfStorageAccounts int = 4

var storageAccountSku = 'standard_LRS'

var storageAccountNames = [for i in range(0,numberOfStorageAccounts): 'st${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id, string(i))}']

resource storageAccounts 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = [for st in storageAccountNames: {
  name: st
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountSku
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}]

output resOut array = storageAccountNames

output resOutObj array = [for (st, i) in storageAccountNames: {
  Index: i
  Name: storageAccounts[i].name
  Id: storageAccounts[i].id
}]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. When I put that code in :  `output resOut array = [for (st, i) in storageAccounts : st.name `  I get  the error on `storageaccounts` in vscode with latest bicep extension (Directly referencing a resource or module is not supported, apply an array indexer to the expression).. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Sorry, that's what happens when you write it from memory.  I've amended the answer 

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an acceptable way of outputting the array? Or is there a better way?

Yes, it is possible to extract the name property of each object in the storageAccounts array and generate a new array with those values in the way you export the array in the last line.

I tried with the same bicep code with adding id properties and got excepted results:

**`test.bicep`**

```
@description('This is the location which needs to be provided, this is the Azure region')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var storageAccountSku = 'standard_LRS'

resource storageAccounts 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = [for i in range(0, 4): {
  name: '${i}venkat123'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageAccountSku
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}]

output storageNames array = [for i in range(0,4) : {
     Name:storageAccounts[i].name
     Id:storageAccounts[i].id}]
```

Deployed using below command:

```
 az deployment group create --resource-group <Your-resource-group> --template-file test.bicep
```

**Output:**

```
"outputs": {
      "storageNames": {
        "type": "Array",
        "value": [
          {
            "Id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/0venkat123",
            "Name": "0venkat123"
          },
          {
            "Id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/1venkat123",
            "Name": "1venkat123"
          },
          {
            "Id": "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/v-venkat-mindtree/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/2venkat123",
            "Name": "2venkat123"
          },
          {
            "Id": "/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/3venkat123",
            "Name": "3venkat123"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]