# Arm Template skip "defined multiple times in a template" error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I have a bicep file which creates resources based on values in array. To simplify I have something like below. The input array is a common configuration and it can have duplicate values as well. However, using a for loop throws "**resource defined multiple times in a template**" error. This can be resolved by adding an IF condition. But I need to add an extra flag. Is there a better workaround ?

```
param storages array = [
'test'
'test'
]

resource st 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = [for st in storages: {
name: st
location: resourceGroup().location
sku: {
  name: 'Standard_LRS'
}
kind: 'StorageV2'
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> The input array is a common configuration and it can have duplicate
> values as well. However, using a for loop throws "**resource define multiple times in a template**" error.

The above error occurs when you try to create with the same name for the resource in the environment.

You can use the below bicep code to create a storage account with the storageAccounts array and generate a new array with those values in the way to export the array in the last line.

**`test.bicep`**

```
param location string = resourceGroup().location
resource storageAccounts 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = [for i in range(0, 2): {
  name: 'venkyst${i}'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
}]

output storageNames array = [for i in range(0,2) : {
     Name:storageAccounts[i].name
     Id:storageAccounts[i].id}]
```

Deployed using the below command:

```
az deployment group create --resource-group <Your-resource-group> --template-file test.bicep
```

**Output:**

```
"outputs": {
      "storageNames": {
        "type": "Array",
        "value": [
          {
            "Id": "/subscriptions/7xxxresourceGroups/venkatesan-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/venkyst0",
            "Name": "venkyst0"
          },
          {
            "Id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/venkatesan-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/venkyst1",
            "Name": "venkyst1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[azure - Is outputting the array in Bicep in this example the correct way? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76512208/is-outputting-the-array-in-bicep-in-this-example-the-correct-way/76513088#76513088) by GordonBy.

Comment: I don't want to create resources with different names. I'm expecting for a workaround to create if new or update if exists. At least extract the unique values from input array

Comment: @DxG you need to use the' if' condition to create if new or update if it exists with names.

Comment: could you please provide an example how to achieve it in a 'for loop' in question